# Google Chrome/Edge keep form data when moving page backwards and forwards, but doesn't update $scope values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

When filling out a form on google chrome/edge(doesn't happen on firefox), then pressing the back page button, then forward page button you get a weird situation where the browser maintains the information in the form. The issue comes when on submitting the form none of the values are saved to the $scope values associated to them.
How can I either disable google/edge from doing this or make it so when they do it the $scope is updated?

Comment: set autocomplete to false on said elements

Comment: I do not want to disable the autocomplete feature from the browser, just the form maintianing data. Will this disable the browsers built in autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Dean Van Greunen has said. Configuring **autocomplete** inside `<input>` will only disable the autocomplete feature of the attribute-applied `<input>` element. You will not worry about the browser's autocomplete feature.

What's more, "Forwarding" the "backwarded" page will preserve your data according to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/win-wizards?redirectedfrom=MSDN#navigation):

> For example, if the user makes changes, clicks Back and then Next, those changes should be preserved. Users don't expect to have to re-enter changes unless they explicitly chose to clear them.

So if you don't want the browser to preserve your data, you can either clear the data before "backwarding" the page or simply disable the input autocomplete feature. Also, simply moving the page back and forth will not trigger the $scope to update.